# Show that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} \geq \frac{9}{a+b+c}$ for positive $a,b,c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Show that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} \geq \frac{9}{a+b+c}$, if $a,b,c$ are positive.

Well, I got that $bc(a+b+c)+ac(a+b+c)+ab(a+b+c)\geq9abc$.

Comment: An alternate and popular form of Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality is $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a_i^2}{b_i} \ge \frac{(\sum_{cyc} a_i)^2}{\sum_{cyc} b_i}$$ for $b_i > 0$. You may recognise this form above.

Comment: While I agree that this is kindof an interesting inequality, what is it with asking questions about "Beautiful X"?  I count _twelve_ of your current 43 questions with "beautiful" in the title.

Comment: @GraphicsResearch idk, just that more people see them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Approach 1**: Write the desired inequality as 
$$
(a+b+c)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)\geq 9\tag{i}
$$
and use the AM-GM inequality $x+y+z\geq 3(xyz)^{1/3}$ to each sum in the parentheses above.

---

**Edit**: just a few more approaches (among potentially many others). Hope you'll find this useful.

**Approach 2**:
Multiply out the LHS of (i) as
$$
1+1+1+\left(\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{b}\right)+\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right)+\left(\frac{a}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right)
$$
and use $x+y\geq 2\sqrt{xy}$ 3 times.

**Approach 3**: Use Cauchy-Schwarz like Macavity suggested below:
$$
\left(\sqrt{a}^2+\sqrt{b}^2+\sqrt{c}^2\right)\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}}^2+\sqrt{\frac{1}{b}}^2+\sqrt{\frac{1}{c}}^2\right)\geq(1+1+1)^2=9
$$

**Approach 4**: Use Jensen's inequality: the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is convex for $x>0$ so:
$$
\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)=\frac{1}{3}f(a)+\frac{1}{3}f(b)+\frac{1}{3}f(c)\\
\geq f\left(\frac{1}{3}(a+b+c)\right)=\frac{3}{a+b+c}
$$
from which you can rearrange to obtain your claim.

**Approach 5**: Please also look up the [Chebyshev's sum inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality) from which your inequality is an immediate consequence.

Comment: Or directly by Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality +1.

Answer (score 2):

Divide both sides of your inequality by (a+b+c), so you now have

$$bc+ac+ab\geq\frac {9abc}{(a+b+c)}$$

Now divide both sides by a so you get

$$\frac{(bc)}{a} + c +b \ge\frac {9bc}{(a+b+c)}$$

Next divide by b

$$\frac c a + \frac a b + 1 \ge \frac {9c}{(a+b+c)}$$

Finally, divide by c

$$\frac 1 a + \frac 1 b + \frac 1 c \ge \frac 9{(a+b+c)}$$

(I have used > instead of greater than or equal to because I can't get that symbol on my keyboard.)

Comment: You can type $\geq$ it as \$\geq\$.

Comment: So you are multiplying the inequality by $abc$ and then dividing it by $abc$. Or what have you done?

Answer (score 2):

$$
(a+b+c)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)\geq 3\sqrt[3]{abc}\times 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{abc}}=9.
$$

Answer (score 2):

it is $\frac{a+b+c}{3}\geq \frac{3}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}}$ $AM-HM$

Comment: I think your answer is correct and indeed very good, but you should explain it a little bit. At least mention that AM and HM stand (I assume) for "arithmetic mean" and "harmonic mean", and that you are using the general result that, given a set of positive numbers, $1/AM \leq HM$

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: If that is correct, @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, then [edit] it into your answer, instead of leaving it buried in comment where no one will see it.